Additional Information Required During Requirements Analysis for Database Design
I am a student currently Studying in Financial Technology in Kitchener. so I have an academic assignment focused on database design, and I need some expert advice. As part of my assignment, I need to understand the additional information that should be collected during the requirements analysis phase specifically for file and database design, which may not be as relevant in earlier phases of systems development.
This is the question below  I need to do for the assignment.
Find a systems analyst or database administrator within your company or any other company that uses a database management system to organize the company’s corporate data, and ask this person to describe what “additional information” should be collected during requirements analysis that is needed for file and database design but that is not very useful for earlier phases of systems development. Provide practical real-world examples.
Can you please help me out?
Thank You in advance

If I were "a systems analyst or database administrator within your company", and you approached me this this question, I would have absolutely no idea what you're talking about. The question assumes that the said analyst or DBA knows what exactly is "useful" at "earlier phases of systems development", and what is not, which makes zero sense for people in those roles. I hope you're not paying too much for your studies.

Aspects like size of data, hardware and performance requirements may be some of these "additional information".
